# Permission problems with Apache on Centos

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

I've set up a LAMP machine with Centos, apache, MySQL and PHP 7.4.

my user via ssh is `mformisano`, I'm able to login via SFTP with `mformisano` and browse folders.
It's an intranet machine, so we are not so severe on restrictions, but, if I type the address into the browser I can execute PHP files, but these files are not able to extract files, create files, etc into the `var/www/html` folder.

Actually the www folder is:

```
drwxr-s---.  4 apache apache   31 29 ott 22.34 www
```

inside:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root   root   4096 29 ott 22.34 ..
drwxr-x---.  2 apache apache    6 19 ott 15.54 cgi-bin
drwxrwxr-x+  3 apache apache 4096  2 nov 10.49 HTML
```

If I give permission to `mformisano`, I can browse via FTP, PHP is executed.
If I give permission to `apache:apache` I cannot browse, PHP is executed.
If I give permission to `mformisano:apache` I can browse, PHP is executed.
If I give permission to `mformisano:mformisano` I can browse, PHP is not executed.

I do need to both browse and execute PHP, so `mformisano:apache` should be the right way, but when I execute kickstart.php (a WordPress plugin that extracts a .jpa archive) this is not extracting and give me an error about writing permissions.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP files are going to be parsed by Apache. Typically Apache will be running under the user www-data, in any case find out what user Apache is running under and give the appropriate permissions to the user that apache is running as. If you are a single person running the sever I would recommend SFTP login as root user, this will give you permissions to modify whatever you want on the server, but remember to change the owner and groups for any files you create as root user before logging out.